# Untrusted code in hadoop

Tags: security, hadoop, multi-tenant, trusted-vs-untrusted

Bob and Alice are working in different divisions of an organization. They use a Hadoop cluster in multi-tenancy mode with Yarn and Kerbros authentication. It is clear that Bob cannot read Alice's data directly because Namenode and hdfs checks permissions.

Can Bob read Alice's files or chunks of data from his mappers and reducers? Why not? How code isolation works?